# How can i fetch value in JSON file by tag and city options with vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Firstly my english is not good. Sorry about that.

1-) My case is: when I write the necessary info into the gaps,- for example job name for one gap and for the other gap the city name(like istanbul)- I want to see the jobs in that city on page.

2-) Also, when i use the box to search for something, i need to use capital letters in order to see result. I want to see the result no matter how i type the letter, capital or not, How can i achieve this?

Thanks for all help.

[this is full code](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/JaWGNW)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    founded: [],
    search: "",
    show: false,
    city: ""
  },
  created() {
    fetch("job.json")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.founded = res.items;
      });
  },
  computed: {
    filteredFounded: function() {
      return this.founded.filter(items => {
        return (
          items.cityName === this.city && items.positionName.match(this.search)
        );
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
  <div class="header">
        <h4>Get Job</h4>
    </div>



    <div id="app" class="nested">
        <div class="card w-50">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="job" v-model="search" placeholder="Job..." @keypress.enter="founded">
                <select name="" class="city" id="" v-model="city">
                    <option value="Seçiniz">Seçiniz</option>
                    <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
                    <option value="Ankara">Ankara</option>
                    <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
                    <option value="Çanakkale">Çanakkale</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="find">
                <button @click="show = true">Find!</button>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body" v-show="show" v-for="items in filteredFounded">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{items.companyName}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.positionName}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.cityName}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.townName}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.distance}}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[and this is job.json file](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=8be3ee357fea49779844f936c4e17907)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by first turning the required data into lower or uppercase letters. You do this using the **toLowerCase()** or **toUpperCase()** functions and then compare the data. For example, you can do something like this.

```
computed: {
            filteredFounded: function () {
                return this.founded.filter(items => {
                    return (
                        items.cityName.toLowerCase() === this.city.toLowerCase() && items.positionName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
                    );
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yess! Thanks for help.

Comment: So what do you think of the first problems?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, it seems to work as expected. However, all your data in the JSON file is in the city of İstanbul. If you, for instance, add another job in Ankara, it seems to also work fine.

Comment: when i delete job field vue shows every json items. for example: write Front-End and select istanbul and click find. it seems good. but if we want delete Front end tag, all jobs or value in json file comes to page. because i did if click button shows data.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to hide the jobs if there's nothing in the job input. In that case, just add the following. `<div class="card-body" v-show="search.length" v-for="items in filteredFounded">` This will hide the list if no input is entered.

Comment: Yes its work partially but this time find button doesnt work :(

Comment: Ok, so if you want to filter data only on button click do the following. Add `filteredFounded: []` to data. Add **setFounded** method, `setFounded() {
                    this.filteredFounded = this.founded.filter(items => {
                        return (
                            items.cityName.toLowerCase() === this.city.toLowerCase() && items.positionName
                            .toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
                        );
                    });
                }` Add event to button. `<button @click="setFounded">Find!</button>` Remove computed.